# installing Infinity Hugo theme in Blogdown new project

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I am trying to create a new project to design a website in R for my wedding using blogdown. I've found a few tutorials on how to load “gcushen/hugo-academic” into the new project: Hugo theme [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbXdr.png). would anyone know codes for this using other Hugo themes, or if not, is there a way to install and change themes in Studio after loading “gcushen/hugo-academic”?

This would be a huge help and I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You read [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/other-themes.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first part of `gcushen/hugo-academic` refers to the github user and the later part refers to the repository containing the theme. For the theme you have already found, you can find it here: https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic. Therefore taking this logic, we can apply the theme from https://github.com/rhazdon/hugo-theme-hello-friend-ng in rstudio as: `rhazdon/hugo-theme-hello-friend-ng`

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try! Also thank you for not saying “what did google say” or “this isn’t a question for here”. Just getting a straight forward answer is appreciated!

Comment: Hi Jonah, no problem and I totally get what you mean! There's too many big headed people on here. If you find this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.